# How do I use ffmpeg in my renderer process in electron?

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, electron

I'm trying to use ffmpeg in my renderer process in my electron app. I expose the modules in my preload.js file like this:

```js
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
const ffmpegStatic = require('ffmpeg-static');
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
// make ffmpeg available as a function in the renderer process
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('ffmpeg', () => ffmpeg(ffmpegStatic.path));
```

And I try to acces it in my renderer.js file like this:

```
video.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    const filePath = file.path;
    const fileName = file.name;
    const fileExt = fileName.split('.').pop();
    const newFileName = fileName.replace(fileExt, 'mp4');
    const newFilePath = filePath.replace(fileName, newFileName);

    // Run FFmpeg
    ffmpeg()

        // Input file
        .input(filePath)

        // Audio bit rate
        .outputOptions('-ab', '192k')

        // Output file
        .saveToFile(newFilePath)

        // Log the percentage of work completed
        .on('progress', (progress) => {
            if (progress.percent) {
                console.log(`Processing: ${Math.floor(progress.percent)}% done`);
            }
        })

        // The callback that is run when FFmpeg is finished
        .on('end', () => {
            console.log('FFmpeg has finished.');
        })

        // The callback that is run when FFmpeg encountered an error
        .on('error', (error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
});
```

But then I get following error in the console: Uncaught TypeError: ffmpeg(...).input is not a function at HTMLInputElement.
I really don't know how to fix this, can anyone help me?

I tried writing it differently and defining ffmpeg in my rendere.js but nothing worked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using [`contextBridge`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/context-bridge) correctly.

First, the second parameter of `contextBridge` should be an object, not a function:

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('ffmpeg', {
  doSomething: () => ffmpeg(ffmpegStatic.path)
})
```

And then, you can only access it from `window`:

```
window.ffmpeg.doSomething();
```

Also keep in mind that preloads are [`sandboxed`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/sandbox) by default, which means that unless you disable `sandbox` in the `webPreferences` of your window, you can't require ffmpeg modules in the preload. If you want to keep sandboxing (as it is a security feature), you need to use [IPC](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc) to communicate between your renderer process and your main process (where you can require the modules).